# Does $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}dx=\int_{f^{-1}(x_1)}^{f^{-1}(x_2)}\frac{f^{\prime}(y)}{y}dy$ hold?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-transforms

Consider a differentiable function $f$ that is strictly increasing and positive. Numerical examples seem to show that:

\begin{equation}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}dx=\int_{f^{-1}(x_1)}^{f^{-1}(x_2)}\frac{f^{\prime}(y)}{y}dy,
\end{equation}
where $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of $f$ and $f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)$.

I was unable to show this and could not find any reference, so that by now I wonder whether this equality holds at all or if the examples I checked were just lucky coincidences.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hint. Substitution: $y=f^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the given formula holds. As regards your last comment, the answer is no, making the substitution $y=f^{-1}(x)$, we don't find
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}dx=\int_{f^{-1}(x_1)}^{f^{-1}(x_2)}\frac{y}{f^{\prime}(y)}dy.$$
By letting $y=f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(y)=x$ and $f'(y)\,dy=dx$. Moreover, since $f$ is increasing, the same holds for $f^{-1}$ and $[x_1,x_2]=[f^{-1}(x_1),f^{-1}(x_2)]$. Hence
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}dx=\int_{f^{-1}(x_1)}^{f^{-1}(x_2)}\frac{1}{y}(f'(y)\,dy).$$
You may also obtain the same result by using the [substitution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals)
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}g(\varphi(x)) \varphi'(x)\,dx=\int_{\varphi(x_1)}^{\varphi(x_1)}g(y)\,dy$$
where
$$g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x\cdot (f^{-1})'(f(x))}\quad\text{and}\quad\varphi(x)=f^{-1}(x).$$

Comment: You're absolutely right. I simply mixed it up completely...